# Prove that if $XA=0$ only for $X=0$ then $A$ invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix over $\Bbb R$, and $W$ be a vector space of all matrices $X$ such that $XA = 0$. How can I prove that 
$W = \{0\}$ implies $A$ is invertible?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the endomorphism of $V:=Mat_n(\mathbb{K})$ given by the multiplication by $A$. $\mu_A:V\longrightarrow V$, $\mu_A(X)=X·A$. This is a linear mapping, $\mu_A\in End(V)$ and $\ker{\mu_A}=W=\{0\}$ so it is injective. Being a linear map between vector spaces of the same dimension ($V$ and $V$ :D) this implies that is also surjective, so $\exists X\in V$ such that $X·A=I$ (and in the ring of square matrices you have left inverse iff you have right, for a given matrix)